# Webkit (Chrome/Safari) not detecting attribute changes

Tags: css, webkit, selector

As usual I developed it in Firefox. Usually it works without modification in Chrome/Safari, and also IE8.

But when I tested on Chrome and Safari, I was surprised to see that it does not work.

My CSS is valid (validated on w3c). The JavaScript (using jQuery) seems to be valid too.

The affected elements are not redrawn after an attribute value is modified through jQuery, so the CSS rules for the new attribute value are not applied, not until I go into the Chrome inspector and deselect/select them manually...

Update: I do not have a working link for this problem anymore.

The problem was that Webkit was not "redrawing" when attributes were changed, but only when classes where changed, so CSS blocks with selectors such as `div[attr=value]` would not apply when attribute `attr` was changed to `value`  through JavaScript.

One workaround is to use classes instead of attributes (`.className`) in selectors. Performing a class change after changing an attribute would also  trigger a redraw also fix the problem.

This post is more than 5 years old, I believe the problem has been fixed in Chrome now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues seems to come from the fact you are using attributes (`selected` attribute on DIVs) to control the state of your images; it seems like the webkit engine doesn't update the graphics until something actually changes - like a class or a style property.

In general, you should know that using a custom attribute like that isn't best practice. You can use a class to indicate when it's on, and `.addClass("selected")`,`.removeClass("selected")` when needed.
Also, you can display the images as background image of an element and control it directly from CSS, with:

```
.item div.caption { background-image: url('bras/B/btn.png'); }
.item.selected div.caption { background-image: url('bras/B/btn_selected.png'); }
```

this will simply change the image according to the `div.item` `selected` class.

For a simple work-around, you could add at the bottom of your `.click` handler something like `$("body").toggleClass("somethingrandom");`, but I really recommend to change your code to work with CSS, background-images and classes.

Comment: Exactly, I changed all the code to rely on classes instead of attributes, and it fixed all problems. I wonder if this is a bug in the Webkit engine.

Comment: @Rolf:  It probably had more to do with the `</head>` tag at the end of the document than a bug in Webkit.

Comment: @Sparky672: The head was properly closed. The elements were being rendered properly. I also reproduced the problem without the head tag mistake, and the results are the same.

Comment: @Rolf:  **Dvir Azulay** certainly deserves this check-mark.  I'm just pointing out that you can't claim there's a "bug" in something while the code needed some improvement.  That's all.  I'm glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1):

Have you opened the error console within Safari yet?

In mine, I'm getting **404 errors** on two files...

```
/bras/bras/A/3/2/1/bra.png
```

and

```
/bras/bras/A/1/pink/3/bra.png
```

---

**EDIT:**

You also have a `</head>` tag at the very end of your document instead of a `</html>` tag.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. Thanks. But I'm pretty sure this is unrelated to the problem, just some missing images.

Comment: Fixed :) I don't know how you spotted it!

Comment: @Rolf:  The error console picked it up.  And this made no difference to the problem??

Comment: Nop, does not seem to affect the problem, just tested.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to modify the attribute value only? Could quite easily add a 'selected' class to the `<div class="item" />` instead/as well. Using this alone/as well as your attribute targeted css will automatically update the images display.

Comment: Thanks for the great tip! I already changed my code to rely on classes and not attributes anymore. Too bad, I liked the added flexibility and power of attributes.